# Is it possible to get Qt Creators Ui designer to create slots for a class that it doesn't recognize?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator

That is, creating slots by right-clicking a widget and selecting "go to slot...".

Example 1, this works:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

This doesn't, because apparently the designer looks for Ui::MainWindow* and completely freaks out if it can't find it (getting "The class containing 'Ui::MainWindow' could not be found ...")

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <memory>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}



class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Ui::MainWindow> ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I'm basically looking for a way to tell Qt "Yes, I really mean that class. I know it doesn't contain a Ui::MainWindow*, it's ok everything will be alright...". Unless I'm wrong and the class actually needs this to be a plain pointer for some reason.

Comment: UI designer in Qt is a pretty primitive tool and it assumes that your project is organized in a standard way. Why do you need to use STL smart pointers, when Qt has it's own and they are used already?

Comment: @divanov I don't _need_ to use standard smart pointers, I _want_ to use them. "UI designer in Qt is a pretty primitive tool" - in that case I'd expect it to be _more_ configurable rather than less. Anyways, it chokes on `QScopedPointer` too.

Comment: UI designer's code takes care about memory management and if you want to use scoped pointer, there must be a reason for that.

Comment: @divanov Smart Pointer OCD? I'm trying to engrave the pattern "I am _the_ owner, so it goes into a unique_ptr" in my head and I'd rather not violate it if there's no compelling reason to do so. Certainly breaking my tools is compelling enough a reason, that's why I'm asking if and how I can get the designer to play along.

Comment: @Cubic, After 4 years from your question I'm still having your same problem. I wonder if anyone found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

"The class containing 'Ui::MainWindow' could not be found ..." issue happens when QT creator can't find your "mainwindow.cpp" file to place the slot function definition.

Make sure your mainwindow.h has the following as a private variable:

```
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
```

And following include is in your mainwindow.cpp file:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
```

If this doesn't work, there may be a bug with your QT creator. Try updating your software.

Comment: Like I explain in the question, the exact same code worked fine at the time when I used a plain pointer instead of `unique_ptr`. Note that this was 7 years ago, I'm not sure if this is still the current behaviour because both Qt and Qt Creator have changed quite a bit since then.

Comment: Try updating. I found that there were bugs in the past which cause the "The class containing 'Ui::MainWindow' could not be found ..."

Comment: I mean the question was from 7 years ago. I don’t have this problem right now because I haven’t used Qt Creator in over 5 years.